# Is there a special character for tab indention in snowflake?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, trim, space

I need to count words in string in snowflake.
the problem is that between the words there are spaces,
in variety count.

for example:

```
str = '67778        19gj5  7770 202ty524 2024       i900      3290 POC/*'
```

I want to get the number of words- 8.

what I tried:

```
array_size(split(str, ' '))
```

return 27 :(

and

```
array_size(split(str, '\t'))
```

return 1.

any idea please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is implementation of @NickW suggestion with some improvement:

Replace all consecutive [whitespace](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_whitespace.asp) characters (`\\s+`) with single space and split it, use array_size, it will work with all whitespace: spaces, tabs, newlines, etc:

```
WITH t1 AS (
select '67778        19gj5  7770 202ty524 2024       i900      3290 POC/*' as str
    )
    
 select array_size(split(regexp_replace(str, '\\s+',' '),' ')) num_words
 from t1
```

Result:

```
NUM_WORDS
8
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternative solution:

1. Use regex_replace to replace all occurrences of multiple spaces with a single space
2. Split the string using a single space as the delimiter (i.e. what you tried originally)

Answer (score 0):

You could use `SPLIT_TO_TABLE` and `COUNT_IF`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE t AS
SELECT  '67778        19gj5  7770 202ty524 2024       i900      3290 POC/*' AS str;
```

Query:

```
SELECT STR, COUNT_IF(s.VALUE != '') AS num_of_words
FROM t,
LATERAL SPLIT_TO_TABLE(t.str, ' ')s
GROUP BY STR;
```

Output:

```
STR                                                                 num_of_words
67778        19gj5  7770 202ty524 2024       i900      3290 POC/*   8
```

---

EDIT:

Alternatively using `REGEXP_COUNT`:

```
SELECT *, REGEXP_COUNT(str, '\\b\S+\\b') AS num_of_words
FROM t;
```